# Incrementing test data (mobile number) for load testing 1 million registrations

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy, jmeter, jsr

I am trying to load test a Register-Search application which will do as the name suggests for ~5 million mobile numbers. Will be using 100-500 threads with looping through a specific delay between each loop.

I have the functional test JMeter script ready for the same. The only change I want to do is generate the mobile number automatically.

The easiest solution would be doing  having the `mobileNumber` as `${random(${min},${max})}`. But I want to avoid it and get a more linearised approach by using *property* `mobileNumber`

In a JSR223 Sampler (using Groovy script), I was trying to read the property as

```
long number = ${__P(mobileNumber)}
vars.put("mobileNumber", String.valueOf(number))
```

I wish to use the UDV `mobileNumber` thus created in current thread and increment the property  `mobileNumber` by 100. Trying to do:

```
number = number + 100
${__setProperty(mobileNumber, String.valueOf(number))
```

For some reasons it is not working and giving error message Response message:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: number for class: Script1
```

Cant figure out whats wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without any scripting by [using just JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) as:

- `${__longSum(${__P(mobileNumber)},100,tempNumber)}` which

  - reads `mobileNumber` property
  - adds `100` to it
  - stores the result into `tempNumber` variable (however if you don't need it you can omit this)
- `${__setProperty(mobileNumber,${tempNumber},)}` - store `tempNumber` variable value as `mobileNumber` property

Functions used are:

- [__longSum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) - computes sum of 2 or more long values
- [__P](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) - returns value of a JMeter Property
- [__setProperty](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) - assigns value to a JMeter Property

Comment: So I think my solution may go like
**vars.put("mobileNumber", ${__P(mobileNumber))**
To get the value of property mobileNumber and store it to the current thread-loop variable mobileNumber
**${__setProperty(mobileNumber,${__longSum(${__P(mobileNumber)},100,)}**
To increment property mobileNumber